# Spring Data JPA: Sort only by date part of java.time.LocalDateTime column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, jpa

Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Table( name = "order" )
public class Order
{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)" )
    private UUID id;

    @Column( name = "posting_date" )
    private LocalDateTime postingDate;

    @Column( name = "created" )
    private LocalDateTime created;

}
```

To search with sorting `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor#findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<T>, org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)` is used

Due to specific case I have to sort by two fields: `postingDate` and `created` and treat `postingDate` as date (not datetime like it is defined in entity), but I don't know how.

To make such a request to MySQL DB, `DATE()` function should be used, like this:

```
select
        order.*
    from
        order o
    where
      ...
    order by
        date(o.posting_date) desc,
        o.pae_created desc
```

But I want to use JPA methods to search and sort.

**Question**: Is there any way to tell JPA that this or that column to sort should be wrapped with some function? How to do so?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to use Spring `Sort`/`Pageable` to achieve this.  It should be fairly straightforward with Hibernate/Criteria API/JPQL though.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in principle doable. I did not run the following code though! Additionally, the `function` keyword was added to JPA 2.1, if you are using an earlier version this will probably not work.

JPQL:

```sql
SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE ...
ORDER BY
  function('DATE', o.postingDate) DESC,
  o.created DESC
```

This is also supported by the Criteria API.

Comment: okay but how to apply it to sorting? Can't find the way even through Criteria API

Comment: The `function('DATE',...)` is in the `ORDER BY` clause, what else are you needing? With criteria API is something along the lines of `query.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.function("DATE", Date.class, root.get("postingDate"))))`